# Finding the index of a string within another string in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, position

I want the find the index of the string that contains another string within a list of n items.

```
MyList = ['acdef','GFDGFDG gfdgfd', 'Blue234 Sky2bas', 'Superman.424', 'baseball']
MyString = 'ball'
```

I want to get `4`, since `'baseball'` contains `'ball'`

When looking for the exact string, I could use something like

```
MyList.index(MyString)
```

but this won't work with the above scenario since `'ball'` is only a portion of `'baseball'`.

I am also wondering what would happen if I search for a string like `'bas`' considering the fact that it's in the 3rd and 5th items of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line using iterators.

```
(i for i,v in enumerate(l) if MyString in i).next()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyList = ['acdef','GFDGFDG gfdgfd', 'Blue234 Sky2bas', 'Superman.424', 'baseball']
MyString = 'ball'

>>> [i.find(MyString) for i in MyList if MyString in i]
[4]
```

Another example, where `'ball'` appears multiple times:

```
>>> MyOtherList ['foo', 'bar', 'football', 'ballbag', 'foobar']
>>> [i.find(MyString) for i in MyOtherList if MyString in i]
[4, 0]
```

Comment: Let's say my list is
`MyList = ['acdef','GFDGFDG gfdgfd', 'Blue234 Sky2bas', 'Superman.424', 'base ball']` 
`MyString = 'base b'`

I get [0]. How can I cover strings with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i, s in enumerate(MyList) if MyString in s]
```

does what I was looking for and works in strings containing spaces